# sharepoint 2013 _api/$metadata error 'A nonnullable DataProperty cannot have a null defaultValue. Name: undefined'

Tags: api, sharepoint, metadata, breeze

I try to use sharepoint 2013 rest api with breezejs.
I get **error**

```
A nonnullable DataProperty cannot have a null defaultValue. Name: undefined
```

when breezejs validates  returned metadata (_api/$metadata). 
With breeze.EntityManager("/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/") all works.

What are the ways to fix it?

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/SharePointProject7/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SharePointProject7/scripts/q.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SharePointProject7/scripts/datajs-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SharePointProject7/scripts/breeze.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SharePointProject7/scripts/breeze.toq.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SharePointProject7/scripts/app.js"></script>


<div data-ng-app="app">
    <div data-ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        <ul>
           <li data-ng-repeat="c in customers"><input type="text" data-ng-model="c.Title" /></li>
        </ul>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.run(['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    breeze.core.extendQ($rootScope, $q);
}]);

app.service('listData', function () {

    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("/_api/");

    var changes;
    this.getItems = function () {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Lists");
        return manager.executeQuery(query).to$q();
    };

    this.saveItems = function () {

        if (manager.hasChanges()) {


            changes = manager.getChanges();

            manager.saveChanges().to$q(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);
        }
        else {
            alert("Nothing to save");
        };

    };


    function saveSucceeded() {

        alert("OK");
    };

    function saveFailed(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    };
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, listData) {
    function initialize() {
        listData.getItems().then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);

    };

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        $scope.customers = data.results;

    }

    function _queryFailed(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }

    $scope.save = function () {

        listData.saveItems();


    };
    initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to hand write the entity configuration as the SP metadata can be huge and it is not a good idea to pull it down at the beginning of the app load.

First get the SharePoint breeze adapter from breeze labs.

Full details here http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/getting-breezejs-to-work-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api

That post goes step by step on getting this working.